# c++ loop optimization and some errors

Tags: c++, loops

code is not executing the loop properly

specially when the input is 1000 the if loop is not executed properly

program requirement

1) should ask for a sale price for the tickets in dollars (e.g. 15.00)

2)the maximum price for a ticket sale is 999.99

```
bool cPrice = true;
    while (cPrice)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the event ticket price:";
        cin.ignore();
        cin >> eventPrice;
        cout << "test";
        if (eventPrice >= 0 || eventPrice <= 999.99)
        {

            cPrice = false;
        }

        else cout << "the valve is invalid.";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

change your if statement from:

```
eventPrice >= 0 || eventPrice <= 999.99
```

To

```
eventPrice >= 0 && eventPrice <= 999.99
                ^^
```

Should be between 0 and 999.99.